# Error when trying to establish encrypted connection to SQL Server from within Java code

Tags: java, sql-server

I am trying to encrypt my SQL connection to the server side, that is originating from java code base.

```
jdbc:JSQLConnect://localhost:1433;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true
```

By passing this parameters encrypt to make the connection secure and trustServerCertificate for not to validate bew client and server.

While doing that I am getting below error. Any help would be very much appreciated.

> TCP/IP connection failed to host:10.177.222.216 port:1433 com.jnetdirect.jsql.JSQLException: DBComms.error reading input. Context:Read packet header, Unexpected end of stream, readBytes:-1, negative read result, PktNumber:0, ReadThisPacket:0, PktDataSize:8000

Below is the sample program.

```
    public class SqlEncryptionDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

        String driverClassName = "com.jnetdirect.jsql.JSQLDriver";
        String connectUrl = "jdbc:JSQLConnect://localhost:1433;databaseName=IMAGE;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true";
        String userName = "alex";
        String password = "password@123";

        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;

        Class.forName(driverClassName);
        System.out.println(connectUrl);
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectUrl, userName, password);

        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String sql;
        sql = "select * from parameter_info where PARAMETER_NAME='test.info'";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        while (rs.next()) {
            String pName = rs.getString("PARAMETER_NAME");
            String paramValue = rs.getString("PARAMETER_NAME_ID");
            System.out.println("Pname :"+pName +"\n "+ "Param Value :"+ paramValue );
        }
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you read this document? It describes how to use SQL Server's encryption functionality from JDBC: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-ssl-encryption?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I did go through the mentioned document,And with that implementation only i am facing this issue.